# spaCy nlp - tag entities in string

Tags: python, string, nlp, spacy

Lets say I have a string and want to mark some entities such as Persons, and Locations.

```
string = 'My name is John Doe, and I live in USA'
string_tagged = 'My name is [John Doe], and I live in {USA}'
```

I want to mark persons with [ ] and locations with { }.

My code:

```
import spacy    
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(string)
sentence = doc.text
for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.label_ == 'PERSON':
        sentence = sentence[:ent.start_char] + sentence[ent.start_char:].replace(ent.text, '[' + ent.text + ']', 1)
    elif ent.label_ == 'GPE':
        sentence = sentence[:ent.start_char] + sentence[ent.start_char:].replace(ent.text, '{' + ent.text + '}', 1)

    print(sentence[:ent.start_char] + sentence[ent.start_char:])
```

...so with the example string this works fine. But with more complicated sentences I get double quotes around some entities. For the sentence:

```
string_bug = 'Canada, Canada, Canada, Canada, Canada, Canada'
```

returns `>> {Canada}, {Canada}, {Canada}, {Canada},  {{Canada}}, Canada`

The reason why I splitted the sentence string into two was to only replace new words (with higher character positions). I think the bug might be in that I am in looping over `doc.ents`, so I get the old positions of my string, and the string grows for each loop with new [ ] and {}. But feels like there must be some easier way of dealing with this in spaCy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight modification that helped me work with your code.

```
string = 'My name is John Doe, and I live in USA'

import re
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(string)
sentence = doc.text
for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.label_ == 'PERSON':
        sentence = re.sub(ent.text, '[' + ent.text + ']', sentence)
    elif ent.label_ == 'GPE':
        sentence = re.sub(ent.text, '{' + ent.text + '}', sentence)
print sentence
```

Yields:

```
My name is [John Doe], and I live in {USA}
```